# Loading javascript dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have 2 links in my HTML form. When user clicks on the link, I want the related javascript page to load without reloading the whole page

I have used the following code in my HTML page:

```
<body id="b">
<h1>Page that switch between CSS and JS</h1>
<div class="container" id="content">
  <div class="link" id="li">
    <ul class="menu" id="nav">    
      <li><a id="three" href="#" onclick="switchjs1();">JavaScript 1</a></li>
      <li><a id="four" href="#" onclick="switchjs2();">JavaScript 2</a></li>      
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="con">
    <form action="" method="post" class="f1" id="f1">
        <table class="t">
            <tr>
            <td><label>Label 1</label></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="1" value="Show 1" class="btn1"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><label>Label 2</label></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="2" value="Show 2" class="btn2"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><label>Label 3</label></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="3" value="Show 3" class="btn3"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><label>Label 4</label></td>
            <td><input type="button" id="4" value="Show 4" class="btn4"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

And following code for scripting:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];         
    var jsNode = document.createElement('script');
    jsNode.type = 'text/javascript';
    jsNode.id = 's1';

    headID.appendChild(jsNode);

    function switchjs1()
    {
        var js = document.getElementById("s1");
        js.removeAttribute('src');
        js.setAttribute("src", "js1.js");
    }

    function switchjs2()
    {
        var js = document.getElementById("s1");
        js.removeAttribute('src');
        js.setAttribute("src", "js2.js");
    }
</script>
```

By the above code I have created a `<script>` tag and I want to set the value of the `src` attribute depending on the link clicked by the user. But it only loads the JavaScript file which is related to the link that was clicked by the user in first place.  For example, if the user clicks on the link 'javascript 1', it loads the `js1.js` file but it does not load the `js2.js` file when the user clicks on 'javascript 2' link.

Please help me because it has become a big problem.
Thank you.

Comment: Please fix your formatting. Also, what are you trying to achieve? Are you aware that substituting the `src` attribute of a `script` element won't unload the previous script?

Comment: Could you indent the markup and code to make it show up properly? Thanks. :)

Comment: Sorry.. i could not figure out how to indent the markup on this site...:-(

Comment: Fixed formatting and grammar.

Comment: @Abhishek: Highlight the code and click the button with the {}

Comment: If possible, try to not include huge full chunks of code in a question because people don't have time to read through all of it.  Ideally, before asking a question, you should make sure that you boil down to the exact point of failure and then ask about that.

Comment: @Andreas: Thanx 4 ur suggestion...!!!!

Comment: Now can u plz answer my question...?????

Comment: Someone already did; and if you want answers, I suggest you don't **demand** people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

To load javascript dynamically use the following code:

```
function IncludeJavaScript(file) {
if (document.createElement && document.getElementsByTagName) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', file);

    head.appendChild(script);
} else {
    alert('unsupported browser');
}
}
```

you can then insert de javascript at a button click:

```
IncludeJavaScript("url_to_your_javascript");
```

However, i'm wondering if all the eventlisteners are set, you'll probably have to work around that. Calling methods within the new javascript function should not be a problem.

Comment: And there are two links related to two javascript files i have to switch between the two javascript files when user clicks on the link..

Comment: Can you indicate what you mean by 'generating a script'? I mean, you're refering to either js1.js or js2.js right?

Comment: See i have two links on my html form & i just want that when user clicks on a link the javascript file related to that link gets loaded...

Comment: So when the user clicks a link you call the function like this

Comment: sorry, so early posting :). You call the function like this  `code`onclick="IncludeJavascript('js1.js'); RemoveJavascript('js2.js');". `code` Of course you have to also define a function that removes the other javascript file, or write a toggle function

Comment: That is the problem i am not able to understand how to write the code for "RemoveJavascript('js2.js');".. bcoz 'removeChild()' method is not working in my code for some strange reasons...!!!!

Comment: Maybe this works:
function unloadJS(scriptName) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head').item(0);
  var js = document.getElementById(scriptName);
  js.parentNode.removeChild(js);
}